# how to make ScrollView horizontal in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using ScrollView for scrolling the list 
how can i make it horizontal it is appearing vertical

I also tried wrapping up in different views but its not working

for eg:

```js
<View>
<ScrollView>
.
.
.
</ScrollView>
<View>
```

Answer (score 121):

You need to define that you want to active horizontal in `ScrollView`:

```
<View>
  <ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  >
  .
  .
  .
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 28):

### Pass the `horizontal={true}` prop to the `ScrollView` Component.

By default, `ScrollView` is laid out vertically. In order to scroll the content horizontally, you simple need to pass a `horizontal={true}` prop to the `ScrollView` Component, like so:

```js
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>

  <Text>Child 1</Text>
  <Text>Child 2</Text>
  <Text>Child 3</Text>

</ScrollView>
```

The above code will lay out Child 1, Child 2 and Child 3 horizontally instead of vertically.

You can read more on the [official React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#horizontal).

Answer (score 20):

```
<ScrollView horizontal />
```

is all you need.

You don't need to write:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} />
```

because it already is true when you pass the prop in.

Answer (score 19):

You may want to set the props `horizontal` and `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator`

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  pagingEnabled={true}>
  {/* React Component Goes here */}
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 11):

just add `horizontal` inside your `<ScrollView>`

Answer (score 11):

```
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
          <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its worked for me , just need to add horizontal={true} inside the scrollView like

```
     <ScrollView horizontal={true}>    //This is horizonatl


     If you want Vertical scroll 
    <ScrollView>                       //vertical scroll
    <Text>Am vertical scroll </Text> 
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

the horizantal scrollview code is just put horizontal={true} in ScrollView