# React Native Horizontal ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: react-native, expo, scrollview

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to do horizontal scrolling with scroll view but it is not scrolling at all.. it is completely static
I'm currently using `react-native: "0.68.2", expo: "~45.0.0"`

This is my code

```
<ScrollView
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
        contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
        >
          <BookCard/>
          <BookCard/>

        </ScrollView>
```

and the code for the Book Card is

```
const BookCard = styled.View
 background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 70%;
```

I have also added a View with `flex:1` around the scroll view but it still doesn't work... please what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make ScrollView horizontal in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591039/how-to-make-scrollview-horizontal-in-react-native)

Comment: I've already made the scrollview horizontal but problem is that it can't scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually i just worked out the issue ... It was because i set the width of the bookcards to a percentage value that is why it didn't work i.e like if you set the cards to `width:50%` and you put 4 cards in the scrollview , it only scrolls to 2 cards because the 2 cards add up to 100% of the scrollview (i was quite dumb lol)

I replaced the percentage values with px values and no matter the amount of items, it's scrolling perfectly now.. Thank you